# Connecting to Solr using pysolr gives Errno 111: Connection refused

Tags: python, docker-compose, solr, network-programming, pysolr

I have a Flask app that should connect to Solr using [`pysolr`](https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr):

```
import flask as f
import pysolr

app = f.Flask(__name__)
solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/')


@app.route("/ping")
def ping():
    return solr.ping()
```

But running it gives me the error:

`pysolr.SolrError: Failed to connect to server at http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/ping/?: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8983): Max retries exceeded with url: /solr/admin/ping/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f1a085f6510>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))`

(truncated because the traceback is extremely long and gives nothing more of much value)

I know that Solr is running, because I can access `http://localhost:8983/solr` on my web browser just fine.

This occurs no matter whether I reference it in my code as `localhost`, `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1`.

I am running both Solr and my webapp inside `docker-compose`, but I've had the same issue before I used Docker. However, in the event that it's relevant, here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

  solr:
    image: solr
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/solr/
    entrypoint:
    - bash
    - "-c"
    - "precreate-core stable; precreate-core unstable; precreate-core archive; exec solr -f"

  frontend:
    build: ./src
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - solr

volumes:
  data:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being due to Docker after all. Since it's running `frontend` and `solr` as two separate services, you can access the Solr backend by using the hostname `solr` like so:

```
solr = pysolr.Solr("http://solr:8983/solr/<core_name>")
```